# Variable lengths differ help, lm regression and weights, variables have the same number of rows

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm trying to run a weighted squares regression, after creating my weights and trying to add it to my regression function I receive the following error:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = CO2_pc_cmice1 ~   GDP_pc_cmice1_C +  :
> variable lengths differ (found for '(weights)')

The `lm` model has 31 rows and the weights I've created are also 31, I've checked to see if there are `NA`s in either of these and there are not. There are some negative numbers, although I'd be surprised if this was the issue. I've run the formula using both `na.action = na.omit` and `na.action = na.exclude`

I'm also running this with a regression with a sample of 99 and I get the same issue.

My regression is

```
LinearCO2_lowerF <- (lm(CO2_pc_cmice1 ~ PolCiv_incPressFreedom_C + CorpInf_cmice1_C + 
                                        Gov_cmicepos1_C + LitGini_umice_C + 
                                        GDP_pc_cmice1_C + PopDensity_cmice1_C + 
                                        TradeOpen_cmice1_C + Urban_cmice1_C +
                                        poly(Oil_coal_umice_C,2), 
                                        data = mydata_completemice2, 
                                        subset = IncomeL == "L"))
```

Weights created

```
wtsco2low <- 1/fitted( lm(abs(residuals(LinearCO2_lowerF))~fitted(LinearCO2_lowerF)) )^2
```

And the regression with weights

```
LinearCO2_lowerFw <- lm(CO2_pc_cmice1 ~ GDP_pc_cmice1_C + PolCiv_incPressFreedom_C +
                                        CorpInf_cmice1_C + Gov_cmicepos1_C + 
                                        LitGini_umice_C + PopDensity_cmice1_C +
                                        TradeOpen_cmice1_C + Urban_cmice1_C + 
                                        poly(Oil_coal_umice_C,2), 
                                        data = mydata_completemice2, 
                                        subset = IncomeL == "L",
                                        weights = wtsco2low, 
                                        na.action = na.omit)
```

(Have also tried with `na.exlude`)

Is anyone able to help?

Answer (score 4):

The `subset=` argument of R modelling functions is applied to **all** the arguments.  So, it looks as though your weights vector is being subsetted. Since it was already the right length, you get an error.

Consider this example: the data frame has 30 rows, but only 20 are in the subset to be analysed, and I have only 20 weights.  If I use the `subset=` argument, the weights get subsetted and there's an error.

Instead, you can use `subset()` on the data before passing it to `lm()`, and that works.

````
> d<-data.frame(y=rnorm(30),x=1:30)
> w<-rep(2,20)
> 
> lm(y~x,data=d, subset=x>10)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = d, subset = x > 10)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
    -0.3161       0.0189  

> lm(y~x,data=d, subset=x>10, weights=w)
Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ x, data = d, subset = x > 10,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for '(weights)')
> lm(y~x,data=subset(d, x>10),  weights=w)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = subset(d, x > 10), weights = w)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
    -0.3161       0.0189  
```
````